# Where would I place a search function in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I think I'm really close with this, but I'm having trouble placing the search function in my existing code.

I want it so that if the word that's searched corrolates to a `last_name` then the function displays the entire related array. Without the search function, the code works fine as long as I specify the string in the JS. I.e.

```
return item.last_name == "Simpson";
```

will display
    `{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},`

This is great, but I need the user to type in a name and the appropriate array to display.

What I have so far:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="search" id="mySearch" /> <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="return"></div>

<script>

var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]

var simpson = users.find(callback);
function callback(item){
    var x = document.getElementById("mySeach").value;
    return item.last_name == x;
}
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = (function myFunction(){
     return JSON.stringify(simpson);
})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I calling the right function with `onclick`? I'm not even sure if `.value` is the right method for this job. When checking the API it seemed like the most relevant.

Let me know if more detail is needed.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t28jq86/)

Comment: well you are using mySeach in js and mySearch in html, mistake in fiddle too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do something like this. I was having some issues with your fiddle since it myFunction isn't defined before. I modified as such:

```
<script>
var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
    var simpson = users.filter(item => item.last_name == x);
    document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(simpson);
}
</script>

<input type="search" id="mySearch" /> <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="return"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjt8av3q/)

Answer (score 2):

This solution does not allow for partial matches or for case insensitivity. Hope this helps :)

```js
var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}];


 function myFunction() {
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
   for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
     if(users[i]['last_name'] === searchValue){
       document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(users[i]);
       return;
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="mySearch" /> <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="return"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just have to define your `myFunction`. Basically create a function with what you already have so it executes when the button is clicked.

```
//this could be outside because is like the data base
var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]

function myFunction() { //TODO rename it to something more descriptive
    var foundUser = users.find(callback);
    document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(foundUser );
}

//this goes outside because it's other function
function callback(item){
    var x = document.getElementById("mySeach").value;
    return item.last_name == x;
}
```

You could also invoke the funcition on the `input` event so it searchs as the user types.